# 20.04 Server on RaspBerryPi 4B does not finish boot and stops at "spi-bmc2835 fe204000.spi: could not get clk: -517"

Tags: boot, server, kernel, raspberrypi, sd-card

I've installed an Ubuntu Server 20.04 on a SD-card running NextCloud.
Now, after a reboot it refuses to finish boot.
I see:

```
Net: eth0: ethernet@7d580000
starting USB...
No working controllers found
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0 is current device
Scanning mmc0:1...
Found U-Boot script /boot.scr
4624 bytes read in 26 ms (172.9 KiB/s)
## Executing script at 02400000
Failed to load '/initrd.img'
Booting Ubuntu (with booti) from mmc 0:...
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 02600000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x2600000
   Using Device Tree in place at 0000000002600000, end 000000000260eef5

Starting kernel ...
```

Then the console refreshes and I see:

```
[   4.673...] spi-bmc2835 fe204000.spi: could not get clk: -517
```

That stayes forever and I have no clue how to fix that.
Usually I would simply recreate the SD-card and start on new, but in this case I would loose my NextCloud config and data. That is no real drama, but it would take time...

Thanx for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry that I can't help with any productive answer. But it turned out that the SD-card is broken.
There is no way around installing it on new.

Answer (score 0):

I have same trouble. finally, i found that problem is the power . change the power from 5V1A to 5V2A, it works.